# Main method in different class can't detect button press

Tags: java

I'm making a program for practice and it's basically simulating winning/losing Powerball tickets. Anyways, the main class is in `launchPowerBall.java` and the button that I am trying to detect when clicked is in `PowerBallGUI.java`. The button works by itself, however, the main in `launchPowerBall.java` isn't able to detect it even though I set up myself a few setters and getters. Any clue what alternative I can do instead? Because it seems as though even though I run it through a `while(true)` loop and I keep pressing the button, there seems to be no detection from the main method.

Here's the action listener for the JButton:

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // If the button is pressed, delete text field and replace with new content
            setButtonPressed(true);
            outputText.setText("");
            outputText.setText(outText);
    }
});
```

Here's what I'm trying to do for the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Build the GUI object
    PowerBallGUI GUI = new PowerBallGUI();
    GUI.buildGUI();
    //GUI.setTextArea("banana");

    // Build the PowerBall object
    PowerBall roll = new PowerBall();

    while(true) {
        if (GUI.getJButton().getModel().isPressed()) {
            System.out.println("TEST");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the three files if you need to see my code:

```
1) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5950413470202cd1ac6d24e238ff693
2) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/773e4e4454a79c057da78eed038fade1
3) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/82335e634c1f84607d3021b4d683cc65
```

Powerball...

```
public class PowerBall {
    private int[] numbers = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private int[] lotteryNumbers = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private int powerBall;
    private int lotteryPowerBall;
    private double balance;
    private double winnings;

    /*** Constructor Methods ***/
    public PowerBall() {
        powerBall = 0;
        balance = 1000;
        winnings = 0;
    }

    /*** Mutator Methods ***/
    public void randomize() {
        int i;
        int highestNumber = 59;
        int highestPowerball = 32;
        int temp = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            // Choose a random number
            temp = (int)(Math.random() * highestNumber);
            numbers[i] = temp;
        }

        // Choose a random Powerball number
        powerBall = (int)(Math.random() * highestPowerball);

        // Choose the lottery numbers
        for (i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
            temp = (int)(Math.random() * highestNumber);
            lotteryNumbers[i] = temp;
        }

        lotteryPowerBall = (int)(Math.random() * highestPowerball);
    }

    public void calculate() {
        int matches = 0;
        int powerballMatches = 0;

        if (balance > 0) {
            // Check to see if there are any matches between the two sets of numbers
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < lotteryNumbers.length; j++) {
                    if (numbers[i] == lotteryNumbers[j]) {
                        matches++;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check to see if the two different powerball numbers match
            if (powerBall == lotteryPowerBall) {
                powerballMatches = 1;
            }

            // Calculate the balance/winnings if there were any matches
            if (matches == 0 && powerballMatches == 0) {
                balance = balance - 2;
                winnings = winnings - 2;
            } else if (matches == 0 && powerballMatches == 1) {
                balance = balance + 4;
                winnings = winnings + 4;
            } else if (matches == 0 && powerballMatches == 0 || matches == 1 && powerballMatches == 0) {
                balance = balance - 2;
                winnings = winnings - 2;
            } else if (matches == 2 && powerballMatches == 1) {
                balance = balance + 7;
                winnings = winnings + 7;
            } else if (matches == 3 && powerballMatches == 0) {
                balance = balance + 7;
                winnings = winnings + 7;
            } else if (matches == 3 && powerballMatches == 1) {
                balance = balance + 100;
                winnings = winnings + 100;
            } else if (matches == 4 && powerballMatches == 0) {
                balance = balance + 100;
                winnings = winnings + 100;
            } else if (matches == 4 && powerballMatches == 1) {
                balance = balance + 50000;
                winnings = winnings + 50000;
            } else if (matches == 5 && powerballMatches == 0) {
                balance = balance + 1000000;
                winnings = winnings + 1000000;
            } else if (matches == 5 && powerballMatches == 1) {
                balance = balance + 10000000;
                winnings = winnings + 10000000;
            }
            //System.out.println("There is currently " + matches + " number matches.");
            //System.out.println("There is currently " + powerballMatches + " powerball number matches.\n");

        } else {
            System.out.println("YOU ARE BROKE!");
        }
    }

    /*** Accessor/Observor Methods ***/
    public void displayBalance() {
        System.out.print("Your balance is at: $");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", balance);
    }

    public void displayWinnings() {
        System.out.print("\nYou have currently won: $");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", winnings);
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();

        if (numbers.length == lotteryNumbers.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if (i < numbers.length - 1) {
                    builder.append(numbers[i] + ", ");
                    builder2.append(lotteryNumbers[i] + ", ");
                } else {
                    builder.append(numbers[i] + " + ");
                    builder2.append(lotteryNumbers[i] + " + ");
                }
            }
        } else {
            return "ERROR: Numbers max set of numbers doesn't match Lottery Numbers max set of numbers!\n";
        }
        return "Your set of numbers were: " + builder + Integer.toString(powerBall) + 
                "\nThe powerball numbers were: " + builder2 + lotteryPowerBall;
    }
}
```

Launcher

```
public class launchPowerBall {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // Build the GUI object
        PowerBallGUI GUI = new PowerBallGUI();
        GUI.buildGUI();
        //GUI.setTextArea("banana");

        // Build the PowerBall object
        PowerBall roll = new PowerBall();

        while(true) {
            if (GUI.getJButton().getModel().isPressed()) {
                System.out.println("TEST");
            }
        }

        //System.out.println("TOO LATE!");
        //while (true) {
            /*roll.randomize();
            System.out.println(roll.toString());
            roll.calculate();
            roll.displayBalance();
            roll.displayWinnings();
            Thread.sleep(500); */
        //}
    }   
}
```

GUI

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class PowerBallGUI {
    private JButton start = new JButton("Launch the Powerball!");
    private boolean buttonPressed = false;
    private String outText;

    /*** Constructor Methods ***/
    public PowerBallGUI() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea("Press the 'Launch the Powerball' button to start!");
    }

    /*** Setters ***/
    /*** Sets the JTextArea object ***/
    public void setTextArea (String str) {
        this.outText = str;
    }

    public void setButtonPressed (Boolean bool) {
        this.buttonPressed = bool;
    }

    /*** Getters ***/
    public Boolean getButtonPressed() {
        return this.buttonPressed;
    }

    public JButton getJButton() {
        return this.start;
    }

    /*** Builds the GUI ***/
    public void buildGUI() {
        // Create the Java Frame itself
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Can YOU win the Powerball? v1.0 (Programmed by: Josh Yang)");

        // Sets the default close operation of the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Sets the size of the frame
        frame.setSize(800, 500);

        // Sets the location of the frame
        centerGUI(frame);

        // Allows the frame to be seen
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Disables frame resizing
        //frame.setResizable(false);

        // Create the Java Panel itself
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel launchPanel = new JPanel();

        // Sets the sides of the Java panels
        panel.setSize(800, 150);

        // Set the panel background color
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        contentPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        launchPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        // Add the panel onto the frame
        frame.add(panel, "North");
        frame.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(launchPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Set top panel's preferred size dimensions
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 100));

        // Adds components onto the panel
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Can YOU win the lottery? v1.0", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 25));
        panel.add(title);

        String text = "Basically, we start you off at $1000 and buy tickets in increments of $2 until you win big (if you do, that is)!";
        JLabel description = new JLabel();
        description.setText(text);
        description.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        panel.add(description);

        // ContentPanel area
        JLabel cDescription = new JLabel("Output: ");
        contentPanel.add(cDescription);

        JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea(17, 60);
        outputText.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        outputText.setEditable(false);
        outputText.setText("Press the 'Launch the Powerball' button to start!");
        contentPanel.add(outputText);


        start.setLocation(100, 100);
        launchPanel.add(start);

        // Add an action listener to the JButton
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // If the button is pressed, delete text field and replace with new content
                setButtonPressed(true);
                outputText.setText("");
                outputText.setText(outText);
            }
        });



        frame.revalidate();

        //frame.pack();
    }

    /*** Centers the GUI based on screen size ***/
    public static void centerGUI(Window frame) {
        // Gets the size of the screen
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
        int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

        // Set the frame location based on x and y
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine that your `while` loop is going to loop really really fast and not allow for any other input

Comment: @ScaryWombat Am I out of options? Will I need to implement the GUI back onto my main method?

Comment: follow a tutorial that shows you how to code a GUI

Comment: That's why you have a listener. Assuming that `GUI.getJButton()` returns the `start` button mentioned above, you can move your `System.out.println("TEST");` to the listener.

Comment: Or you can have a Boolean variable that will be set true when the button is pressed.

Comment: Why not attach a listener, like `ActionListener` to the `GUI` so it can notify the caller when something actually happens?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that's what I did, I think? If you check in PowerBallGUI.java (I provided the links) on line 114 I put in an action listener that when the button is pressed, it also sets off `setButtonPressed()` where I can retrieve it from my main method using `getButtonPressed()`. However, that doesn't work. :(

Comment: @THEMAN No, rather the polling the GUI for the information you need, you need to establish an observer pattern which would allow the GUI to notify the main that something has happended

Comment: @THEMAN The [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) is just a mean by which one or objects can "observe" changes to another object, the event listener API in Swing is an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to take the functionality you're "trying" to execute in the `main` method and put in the `ActionListener`...

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // If the button is pressed, delete text field and replace with new content

        PowerBall roll = new PowerBall();
        roll.randomize();
        System.out.println(roll.toString());
        roll.calculate();
        roll.displayBalance();
        roll.displayWinnings();

        setButtonPressed(true);
        outputText.setText("");
        outputText.setText(outText);
    }
});
```

If you "really" want to do more work in the main, you will need to generate some kind of observer pattern which can notified when something occurs.

You could put one on `Powerball` so it could notify you of a status change or on the GUI which notify you that the start button was pressed

Comment: I never thought of this! Thanks! :D

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)